# Django: Static Image won't load

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have been following the official documentation to the letter, trying some of the advice for related questions on here, and just searching the web in general and I am still having no luck getting one little image to load.

I have an image called 'logo.png' and my project hierarchy looks like this:

```
project/
   mysite/
      app/
         __init__.py
         admin.py
         models.py
         urls.py
         view.py
      mysite/
         __init__.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
         views.py
         wsgi.py
      static/
         logo.png
      templates/
         index.html
         calling_image.html
```

Inside `settings.py` I have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Inside `calling_image.html` I have `<img src="/static/logo.png">`

My template `calling_image.html` is called by `project/mysite/app/views.py` which is of course then called on by `project/mysite/app/urls.py` and I even tried including the following two lines (as I saw suggested a few times) at the end of my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Nothing works, so what have I done wrong?

**Edit**: Sorry I made a type, I have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` with the closing slash in my `settings.py` and for clarification, I am running this on my dev build with `python manage.py runserver`

**Solved**: So I ended up solving this myself. I created a directory `resources` within `project/mysite/` and placed `logo.png` in there. I then set `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "resources"),)` and ran `collecstatic` and everything worked! Didn't need to use `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` and whatnot.

Comment: The proper syntax to reference a static file would be `<img src="{% static "logo.png" %}">` assuming that logo.png is in your top-level static folder. (See also [this part of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial06/)).

Comment: Maybe He needs "rendre_to_response"

Comment: try to close the path to `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and also run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Make sure you have defined ```STATIC_ROOT``` in your settings file

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, I did close the path to `STATIC_URL`. What do I set `STATIC_ROOT` to?

Comment: set ```STATIC_ROOT``` to the main static directory something like ```os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you probably need the variable `STATICFILES_DIRS` defined in your settings.py and that should include the location of that `static` directory holding `logo.png`.

Django only looks for static files inside a `static` directory inside *each app* by default. If you have a static file outside of any app, it won't be picked up by `collectstatic` automatically.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

---

**Confusion Surrounding Staticfiles**

There's always a lot of confusion around Django and Static files. I believe this confusion comes from the fact that it doesn't make any sense for Django to handle static files in **production**, but it seems natural to use it when learning to use Django and thus when initially developing.

The reason it doesn't make any sense for Django to serve static files is that Django is a framework for rendering *dynamic responses*. "Static" files are not dynamic: they don't change. Thus, it's a huge waste of resources to spin up a Python application, which calls all of the Django machinery, just to find and return a file that has no dynamic content.

**Staticfiles: the job of the webserver**

There is something that is really good at serving static files: webservers themselves (such as a Apache, nginx, etc.). That's what they were designed to do. The webserver can run a Python/Django application *or* it can just locate a file and send it back, so you typically configure a webserver by telling it something like the following (in pseudo-server-speak):

> - When someone accesses the path `/static/` let them access the files in
>     the following directory: `/var/www/static/`.
> - When someone accesses the
>     path `/`, spin up this Python application that lives over here:
>     `/var/www/django-app`.

**Django Static Files Tools**

As a result, Django comes with some helper tools that manage static files, so that your actual server can serve them.

These tools are the following(defined in `settings.py`):

- `STATIC_URL`: the URL path where your server will be serving your
  static files. This is just so that when you use the `static` templatetag, that Django knows how to `urlreverse` it. In other words, it's merely a convenient way of turning `{% static "..." %}` into `/static/...`.
- `STATIC_ROOT`: the place on your server (or in the
  cloud somewhere), to which Django *will copy* your static files, so
  that your server can serve them. This copying happens when you run
  `collectstatic`.
- `STATICFILES_DIRS`: any extra directories Django
  should look for static files whenever you run `collectstatic`. By
  default Django only looks in each app's directory for a `static`
  directory (just like with `templates`).

**Static Files In Development**

Okay, but that's not so helpful in development where you are probably using Django's `runserver` command. You don't have a server running that will server static files.

Thus, you can *ask* Django to please also server static files for you in just this one case, because you are developing your application and don't want to run a separate server.

There [is a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve) that automatically should pick up and serve static files when `DEBUG=True`. Alternately, this is also why someone might use the following:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: To extend on this comment, see [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) for how this is related to `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: Interesting, I ended up figuring this out myself (I updated my OP with my solution) and am wondering why I don't need to run the last bit of code appending a pattern onto `urlpatterns`. Thank you so much for clarifying everything else though!

Comment: That's good! I think that's because there is a view that is [automatically enabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve) if you are running in `DEBUG=True` mode. The docs say you only need the `urlpatterns`, "To use the view with a different local development server...".

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:
   `STATIC_URL = 'static/'`
3. Hopes you stored images in folder `projectname/static/appname/images/image.png`
4. Finally in your html simply add the following

`<img src="appname/images/image.png" alt="My image"/>`

[please refer django dcumentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything, nothing worked. In the end it turn out that image was corrupt because I opened it as bytes in Visual Code editor.

Uploaded new image and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, you need to specify `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'` in `settings.py` and you need to have a URL to direct `/static` to your static files. like so.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True
    }),
)
```

This could be a bit outdated but still works for me.

Also, are you trying to get this to work on your dev site with `python manage.py runserver` or on a production site?

**Update**

Here is an example for you main urls.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # more urls...
)

#The following enable structural 'static' files while in development mode.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True
        }),
    )
```

`patterns` is imported near the top of your urls.py file.

This is where `STATIC_ROOT` comes in to play.

You may also need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` in order for your static files to be collected from your various apps and copied into the folder that is `STATIC_ROOT`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018372/where-to-keep-static-files-in-django-application-how-to-server-static-files-fro/26026182#26026182) for a much more in depth explanation :)

Comment: I had two issues with this: where is `pattern` defined/imported from and how do I correctly import `settings.py` into my `urls.py` (and which `urls.py`? The one that uses the template I'm guessing?)

Comment: Also I'm running this on my dev site

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` is a parameter solely for collecting static files to look for in a production setting. I believe you are thinking of `STATIC_URL`, which is mentioned in OP's question.